# PHP how to remove rgb(255, 255, 0); in a string

Tags: php

I want to remove the rgb(number, number, number); in my string using php but I'm not sure what to use

```
<p>asd <span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);">a12</span>asd<span style="font-size: 8px;"></span></p>
```

that the string contains

One of the ways I know is preg_replace but I'm not sure how to remove it without affecting the other number

```
$p = preg_replace(' /[,0-9]+/ ', '', $p);
```

that is what I use but it will remove the **12** in the `span` tag , any recommendation would help, Thanks

the output that i needed is this

```
 <p>asd <span>a12</span>asd<span style="font-size: 8px;"></span></p>
```

that the string contains

I use `str_replace` for the front part

```
$p = str_replace(' background-color:', '', $p);
$p = str_replace(' style=','', $p);
```

I'm thinking of using preg_replace to catch all the different values in the `rgb()` but I don't know how to do it. any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Please post the output how you need?

Comment: What else did you try? Why not use a regular expression that matches the whole part you want to remove, and not solely some parts?

Comment: I use the regular str_replace for the part that i don't need but str_replace cant catch the  rgb(255, 255, 0);

Comment: "str_replace cant catch the rgb(255, 255, 0);" - what does that mean? You haven't shared any code that uses `str_replace`

Comment: @NicoHaase ye that's why I'm trying to use preg_replace but i don't know how to catch the different values in the **rgb()**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use PHP regex: `preg_replace('/style="background-color: rgba?\(\d+, \d+, \d+(, \d+)?\);?"/', '', $p);` - *works only if attribute always in same format*. E.g. remove `;` or add additional style, and regex will fail, because HTML is not regular language
2. Use CSS rules: `p > span {background-color: transparent; !important;}`

Comment: You could make the spaces between numbers optional as well to be even more robust

Comment: Please post how the output you need?

Comment: the output that i needed is this ```<p>asd <span>a12</span>asd<span style="font-size: 8px;"></span></p>```

Comment: I have tried yours but it doesn't seem to remove it. the number in the **rgb()** will be different

Comment: @Justinas is there a way to just remove the **rgb(255, 255, 0)**?

Comment: @MamaWin Check updated version. [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rLlTQx/1)

Comment: @MamaWin Yes, modify regex. But removing only that will leave `<span style="background-color: ;">`

Comment: @Justinas ah yes, i would like it to just to leave ```<span style="background-color: ;">``` i can remove this using str_replace

Comment: @Justinas i have figure it out, thanks for the help.